# How do you go from a user being able to only check one checkbox to multiple checkboxes in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material, selection, angular8

I have an angular app, basically when the user clicks on check me checkbox, I only want the user to be able to select only one check box from the selection list.  If the check me checkbox is  not checked I want the user to be able to select multiple check boxes (default behavior of course).

I was able to get it to where the user can only select one checkbox, but how do I toggle back to where they can go back to multiple check boxes can be checked?

Here is a stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i3pfu2-5wtmpm?file=app%2Flist-selection-example.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the selectOnlyOneEntityFunc to verify if this.isChecked is true or not

```
selectOnlyOneEntityFunc(){
this.selectionList.selectionChange.subscribe((s: MatSelectionListChange) => {
  if(this.isChecked)
    this.selectionList.deselectAll();
  s.option.selected = true;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jmel, isn't that usually the case it is something simple staring at us programmers in the face.